# Caliburn.Micro and app resume

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

In my Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app I enabled the app resume (ActivationPolicy="Resume")

When the user re-open the app (using the main tile), the OnDeactivate method of the ViewModel is called after the OnActivation method.

Is it correct?
How can I handle the app resume with Caliburn.Micro?

Here is the code of the ViewModel:

```
public class Page2ViewModel: Screen
{
    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();

    }


    protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
    {
        base.OnDeactivate(close);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `AppBootstrapper`.

To handle the app fast resume, the `Navigated` and `Navigating` events must be subscribed in the `CreatePhoneApplicationFrame` frame.

In [this](https://github.com/emaori/WinPhone_CM_AppResume_Example) repository the fix (see commit list for the history).

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem right. `OnDeactivate` is called when navigating away from a View. In your ViewModel there is no way to directly differentiate if it was activated from normal navigation or because of resuming.

Take a look at your Bootstrapper, you can override `OnActivate` and `OnLaunch` methods there that correspond to `Application_Launching` and `Application_Activated`. `OnActivate` is the one you want.